# python scrapy building same item from multiple parse functions : calling second parse function in loop

Tags: python, loops, scrapy, scrapy-item

I am trying to build an item from many parsing functions because am getting data from multiple urls,
I try to iterate a dictionary  (that i built using 2 for loops) that's why am using 2 for loops to get the needed variable to generate the URL
then for every variable i call the second parse function passing the needed URL
this is where i want to call the second parse function from my main parse

```
   for r in [1,2]:
      for t in [1,2]:
        dataName = 'lane'+str(r)+"Player"+str(t)+"Name"
        dataHolder = 'lane'+str(r)+"Player"+str(t)
        nameP = item[dataName]
        print('before parse ==> lane = ' + str(r) + "  team = " + str(t))
        urlP = 'https://www.leagueofgraphs.com/summoner/euw/'+nameP+'#championsData-soloqueue'
        yield Request( urlP, callback=self.parsePlayer , meta={'item': item , "player" : dataHolder} )
```

I am using those prints() to see in output how my code is executing
same in my second parsing function which is as following

```
def parsePlayer( self , response ):
  item = response.meta['item']
  player = response.meta['player']
  print('after parse ====> ' + player)
  mmr = response.css('.rank .topRankPercentage::text').extract_first().strip().lower()
  mmrP = player+"Mmr"
  item[mmrP] = mmr
  # yield item after the last iteration
```

( i know i did not explain every detail in the code but i think its not needed to see my problem , not after u see what am getting from those prints )

[result i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iURA.png)

[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIqoa.png)

also for some reason everytime i run the spyder i get diffrent random order of prints this is confusing i think it s something about the `yield` i hope someone can help me with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrapy works asynchronously (as explained clearly in their [official documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html)), which is why the order of your prints seem random.
Besides the order, the expected output looks exactly the same as the result you get. 
If you can explain why the order is relevant, we might be able to answer your question better.

If you want to yield 1 item with data of all 4 players in there, the following structure can be used:

```
    def start_requests(self):
        # prepare the urls & players:
        urls_dataHolders = []
        for r in [1, 2]:
            for t in [1, 2]:
                dataName = 'lane' + str(r) + "Player" + str(t) + "Name"
                dataHolder = 'lane' + str(r) + "Player" + str(t)
                urlP = 'https://www.leagueofgraphs.com/summoner/euw/' + dataName\
                       + '#championsData-soloqueue'
                urls_dataHolders.append((urlP, dataHolder))

        # get the first url & dataholder
        url, dataHolder = urls_dataHolders.pop()
        yield Request(url,
                      callback=self.parsePlayer,
                      meta={'urls_dataHolders': urls_dataHolders,
                            'player': dataHolder})

    def parsePlayer(self, response):
        item = response.meta.get('item', {})
        urls_dataHolders = response.meta['urls_dataHolders']
        player = response.meta['player']
        mmr = response.css(
            '.rank .topRankPercentage::text').extract_first().strip().lower()
        mmrP = player + "Mmr"
        item[mmrP] = mmr
        try:
            url, dataHolder = urls_dataHolders.pop()
        except IndexError:
            # list of urls is empty, so we yield the item
            yield item
        else:
            # still urls to go through
            yield Request(url,
                          callback=self.parsePlayer,
                          meta={'urls_dataHolders': urls_dataHolders,
                                'item': item,
                                'player': dataHolder})
```

Comment: okay that makes sense thank u so much, the order is important to me because i wanted to test at the end if the second parse function manipulated the last variable i sent then it build the item and send it to next parse function or to pipline , in this case i test if the meta variable "player" is equalt to "lane2Player2" that means it manipulated all previous ones and item is fully build and ready to yield,

Comment: In your current logic, 1 item is 1 player (so you have 4 items coming out of your code). If you want to get 1 item for the 4 players, you would have to re-write your loop so it yields a callback to itself, adds the data to the item, and only at the end it yields the 1 item. i'll try to edit my answer to make it more clear

Comment: thank you so much sir this works perfectly and i learned a lot from it